# Why should we say the closing prayer(Tktf)

Tags: salat

Why should we read the closing prayer., Some people believe that this type of prayer is the life of Omar his bean ordered and His Prophet did not read this prayer.

Comment: What do you mean by closing prayer(tktf)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the closing prayer is Shalat Witr ..

> Rasulullah SAW said :
>
> إِنَّ اللَّهَ وِتْرٌ يُحِبُّ الْوِتْرَ
>
> "Verily Allah is Witr and liked the witr (odd)." (Narrated by Bukhari no. 6410 and Muslim no. 2677)
>
> اجْعَلُوا آخِرَ صَلاَتِكُمْ بِاللَّيْلِ وِتْرً
>
> Make you late night prayer is Witr prayer. "(Narrated by Bukhari no. 998 and Muslim no. 751)

Clear from this hadith that the Prophet Muhammad did Witr Prayer.
When the Prophet Muhammad always do at the end of the night the Shahabah Umar often do so at the beginning of the night for fear of his witr prayer will be missed ..

> Rasulullah SAW said to Abu Bakr, "When you perform witr?" Abu Bakr replied, "I do witr at the beginning of the night". And he said to Umar, "When you perform witr?" Umar replied, "I do Witr at the end of the night". Then he said to Abu Bakr, "This guy did with great caution." And he said to 'Umar, "The guys are so strong." (Narrated by Abu Dawud no. 1434 and Ahmad 3/309. Shaykh Al Albani said that this Hadith Sahih)

Wallahu A'lam